# retrieve misclassified documents using scikitlearn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm interested to know if there's built in functions in scikitlearn python module, that can retrieve misclassified documents.

it's simple i usually write it myself by comparing both predicted and Test vectors and retrieve the documents from the test document array. but i'm asking if there's a built in functionality for it instead of copying the functionality in each python code i write.

Comment: If `clf.predict(X_test) != y_test` is all you are looking for, then as you say it is very simple and therefore not exposed as a member function of any classifier. However with maybe a few tricks, you could write a `scoring` object that does this, if you wanted to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a list of true labels `y_test` for a set of documents, e.g. `["ham", "spam", "spam", "ham"]` and you convert that to a NumPy array, then you can compare it with the predictions in a one-liner:

```
import numpy as np

y_test = np.asarray(y_test)
misclassified = np.where(y_test != clf.predict(X_test))
```

Now `misclassified` is an array of indices into `X_test`.

@eickenberg is right, this kind of stuff is not implemented in scikit-learn because users are expected to be familiar enough with NumPy to do it themselves in a few lines of code.

Comment: But if I do a Shuffle Split, can I still use this method to identify my misclassified datapoints? Or if I change the train test split ratio, how would I be able to correctly identify which points are which?

Comment: @user42 this is a very good question! I was wondering the same!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the misclassified like this with a list comprehension. Otherwise I don't know any other way to do this in sklearn.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm


iris = datasets.load_iris()
X_iris, y_iris = iris.data, iris.target
X, y = X_iris[:, :2], y_iris
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

clf = svm.LinearSVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

mis_cls = [train 
           for test, truth, train in 
           zip(X_test, y_test, X_train) 
           if clf.predict(test) != truth]
```